# Can we write bteq on Teradata Aster node

Tags: teradata-aster

I am trying to take the backup of DDL of all of my schemas in Teradata Aster. I know how to take it manually but can some please tell me how i can write bteq on Aster.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use bteq or teradata db syntax directly against an aster database.  If you have a teradata db you may be able to write table queries against aster tables,but this doesn't help with schema type queries.

I think that aster uses a postgress db, so you may find help looking for a postgres solution to your issue.